# Proving that a sequence is a Cauchy sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I must prove that the following sequence is a Cauchy sequence:

$a_{n}=\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}$

(that is, I must show that for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there is N > 1 such that $\left | a_{m} - a_{n} \right | < \varepsilon$ for all m,n > N)

Answer (score 3):

You have that $$|a_n-a_m|=\left|\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt n}-\frac{(-1)^m}{\sqrt m}\right|\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt n}+\frac{1}{\sqrt m}$$

by the triangle inequality. Now make $n,m$ large. You can assume without loss of generality that $m>n$, say. Thus you may only make $n$ large.

Answer (score 2):

Every convergent sequence (with limit s, say) is a Cauchy sequence, so to apply this property you can notice that the sequence $\{a_n\}_n \rightarrow 0$ as $n$ goes to infinity.

Otherwise you can apply directly the definition of Cauchy sequence.
I'll give you an hint for this.

try considering $n_{\epsilon},m_{\epsilon} \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{n_{\epsilon}} < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ (same for $m_{\epsilon}$) and the apply the triangular inequality.

Such $n_{\epsilon}$ exists because ...

Answer (score 2):

The real sequence $(a_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence if and only if it is a convergent sequence which is the case.